# Can we read the entire input of a filter from stdin line by line?

Tags: java

If a have a file with content like below. How can I enter that content in stdin and read it line by line in a have program. If I use `Scanner` it doesn't take the entire content at a time. It only takes line by line after each enter.
File Content

```
10 Bla Blah Blah
20 Bla Bla Bla
20 Bpa bla bla
40 Bla Bla Bla
```

Comment: Using Scanner should be fine. `java com.foo.MyClass < yourfile.txt`. What have you tried?

Comment: No like the contents of the file will be read from stdin. This is a hackerrank challenge. So I don't get to read from the file. The number of lines in the file is also not clear. It just says that there can be upto a 1000 lines.

Comment: Scanner can read from System.in, as from any other input stream. Whether the values coming in System.in come from strings entered in the console, or from a file (using the command shown in my previous comment) doesn't change the way you read from System.in using a Scanner. Again, what have you tried, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? You're free not to believe me or any other person answering you, but then, why do you even ask a question?

Comment: See I tried using scanner but if we copy paste the contents of a file in Stdin, then how do we tell the command line to stop reading when there are no more lines to read. I tried something like this but it does stop.

`Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
 }`

Comment: Don't copy and paste. Use `java com.foo.MyClass < yourfile.txt`.

Comment: No I need to use the contents inside yourfile.text. Reading from the file directly is not a problem. But how do directly use the contents of the file.

Comment: The way I told you twice already. That does not read the file directly. It uses the contents of the file as System.in for the java program. So the Java program reads from System.in, and the contents of System.in is the content of the file. But you won't believe me, so...

Comment: I understood that. But I have no way of giving the file path or the file name. I just have the contents of the file. So forget that a file exists. Its just the contents of a file that are present which need to be read from commond line

Comment: hackerrank will provide the content of the file in System.in when it executes your code, once submitted. To try your code before submitting it, just do what hackerrank will do: `java com.foo.MyClass < yourfile.txt`. That's the 4th time I tell you to do that. You still don't believe anything I say. I wonder why I keep answering.

Comment: Ok now i understand. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: But one last question. How do I do this in eclipse

Comment: I haven't used eclipse for a long time, but in my old install, there is a Common tab in the Run configuration allowing to specify a file as standard input.

Comment: If I use the below code then its reading but isn't reaching the sysout. Somehow it magically stops after executing the while.
`List alist = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
 alist.add(sc.nextLine());
}
sc.close();
System.out.println("Alist is" +alist);`

Answer (score 0):

The following code gets characters from input until user hits Ctrl+D in Linux/Unix or Ctrl+Z in Windows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String text = readUntilEOF(System.in);
}

private static String readUntilEOF(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    char ch;

    do {
        ch = (char) in.read();
        stringBuilder.append(ch);
    }while(ch != CharacterIterator.DONE);

    stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1);
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

The downside of this code is that user must press Enter at the end of each line because if they hit Ctrl+D/Ctrl+Z at the end of a line, that line is entirely ignored. If you want to avoid this problem you can assume another character for showing the end of your input.

Comment: Ctrl-D works only on unixy shell. On Windowsy/dossy shell, EOF is Ctrl-Z on empty line